# Why can't you access JSON directly from the response in Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, fetch

In the example below, why does the first fetch not receive the expected json? How can you have a fetch handle multiple content-types like `application/json` and `image/jpeg`?

```
// outputs: {}
fetch(url)
.then(function(response){
   alert(JSON.stringify(response.json()));
});

// outputs the expected json
fetch(url)
.then(function(response){ return response.json(); })
.then(function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data)) });
```

Answer (score 2):

`response.json()` is not synchronous.  It returns a promise, while the system goes and parses the JSON.

The reson that your second example works is that when you return a promise within a promise, the outer promise waits for the inner promise to resolve.

Comment: Ah. So in the first example, could you do something like `response.json().then(){...}`?

Comment: @GoldenJoe Yes, for sure.  As long as your `alert()` and what not is within the `.then()`.

Comment: Interesting. Is it always necessary to convert to json asynchronously, or can you access the response text synchronously?

Comment: @GoldenJoe Just promises.  Remember, at the time of response, you don't even have the full body downloaded yet.  This first callback is fired when the response headers have been received.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body